# Forests unmounted

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Recently we are seeing the issue of all forests getting unmounted suddenly even the master which leads to customer issues. I want to know the possible reasons that can lead to this situation or how to get the root cause behind this. Can anyone please help.

Comment: What do the log files say is happening?  What activity is happening in the server when this occurs?  There is way too little information here for anyone to even guess at.  Please read the help section for information on asking a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what customer support is for. Assuming you’re a registered customer, email or call support. If you’re still evaluating, contact your account owner. Same if you’re with a partner.